# iOS+How to place image on half of UINavigationbar and UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am using UITableView header to add UIImageView and other labels.
But I am unable to place UIImageView in between navigation bar and UITableViewHeader. my Image is going behind navigation bar.
Pls refer the expected design screenshot. Thanks in advance. pls guide me on this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add an UIImageView in `navigationBar`, something like (I am using SnapKit for demo so ignore it. You can also make frame | autolayout yourself):

```swift
let categoryImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icon_category"))
navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(categoryImage)
categoryImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.width.height.equalTo(50)
    make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
    make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(25)
}
```

Another way is just hide default `navigationbar` then add your custom view instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom navigation bar to place any object on it as we cannot customize the default navigation bar in such ways.